# Error loading DLL from NSIS script when calling to IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()

Tags: c#, .net, nsis

I am building a simple library in C#. This DLL has two functions; one to get the MAC Address of the computer and the other the CPU ID. The final purpose of the DLL is to be called from NSIS script that will call those functions.

I call it this way in the NSIS script:

```
CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD "CypherLibrary.dll" "CpuMacGetter1.HwInfoRetriever" "GetMacAddress" 0
```

The execution returns the following error:

> Error calling .NET DLL method. Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.

It only occurs when I use this kind of objects:

> IPGlobalProperties computerProperties =
>   IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

Or:

> ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");

If I return the current time for instance then there is no problem.

Even more, the error happens only when I build with the .NET 4 Framework but not with .NET 3.5 (yes, I have both of them installed). And if this was not enough in the final user's computer it is the opposite. Works with 4 version but not 3.5.

Any clue behind this behaviour?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is fast a year old, but I think better late than never. :)

### Find the real problem

First we should note that the exception message is too general. A more verbose message would clarify what is the problem. To achieve this you have to modify the NSIS plugin itself.

On the [official page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Call_.NET_DLL_methods_plug-in) of the plugin you can [download](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/images/9/9c/CLR.zip) its source code. Extract and open it with Visual Studio. (I used VS2010.) (After probable upgrade) try to build the solution in debug and release. Release configuration has a post-build event which copies the output DLL to the installed NSIS Plugins folder on your computer. (If you have got an x64 machine, you have to modify this event to add  `(x86)` suffix to the Program Files part of the path.) So every Release build update your current NSIS CLR plugin.

To produce the verbose exception message find the main catch block in `NSIS_CLS_Loader.cpp` (Line 145), and change the message to log `ex->ToString()` instead of `ex->Message`. Rebuild your plugin. (Of course you should use this procedure in development phase, because it dumps the whole stack trace to your display.)

After you also rebuild your NSIS installer and try to install it, you will see a detailed exception message, and you can figure out what is the potential problem. I'm pretty sure it will be a message which tells a dependent assembly could not be loaded. This is a known problem with this NSIS plugin, the author itself states it on the plugin's page:

> Another issue is that if want to call a .NET dll from your .NET dll, you will find that the installer cannot find the second .NET dll. For the moment the remedy is to wrap your installer in another installer. This other installer should place the .NET dlls in the same directory as the installer will run from. When the installer runs, the .NET dlls can now be found. There will only be distributed one setup file.

If the detailed exception message was not the same for you, you have to figure out the solution based on the message. But if you got the same, maybe the following workaround can solve the problem.

### Solution

When you load an assembly and this process fails an `AssemblyResolve` event is raised. A very simple solution is to subscribe to this event and load the dependent assembly in the event handler method.

So subscribe to the `AssemblyResolve` event in the `CallCLR` procedure right before the `LoadAssembly` call in line 51.

```
AppDomain::CurrentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew ResolveEventHandler(&MyResolveEventHandler);
```

Create an event handler and a dictionary object to prevent loading the same assembly multiple times. A concurrent dictionary is used to handle concurrency issues.

```
ref class Container {
public:
    static ConcurrentDictionary<String^, Assembly^>^ LoadedAssemblies = gcnew ConcurrentDictionary<String^, Assembly^>();
};    

static Assembly^ MyResolveEventHandler(Object^ sender, ResolveEventArgs^ args)
{
    AssemblyName^ assemblyName = gcnew AssemblyName(args->Name);
    String^ assemblyFileName = ".\\" + assemblyName->Name + ".dll";

    if (!Container::LoadedAssemblies->ContainsKey(assemblyFileName))
    {
        Assembly^ loadedAssembly = LoadAssembly(assemblyFileName);
        return Container::LoadedAssemblies->GetOrAdd(assemblyFileName, loadedAssembly);
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Don't forget to cleanup the allocated resources at the end of `CallCLR`.

Of course it is essential to modify your NSIS installer to copy the dependent assembly files to the `$PLUGINSDIR` directory.

When I encountered first with this problem it turned out that the plugin could not resolve the `log4net.dll`.

*Special thanks to my colleague, Attila, who provided me the guidelines to this solution.*

Edit (03.10.2013.)

### Deployment

After you build your modified plugin, you have to deploy it to the NSIS' plugins folder (tipically `C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Plugins`) and rebuild your installer. It worked fine on my machine (and also on our Hudson build server), but when I copied the installer to the destination PC, it failed again with the error message `Could not load CLR.DLL`.

It turned out the problem was that I converted the source code's solution to Visual Studio 2012. This conversion also set the target C++ platform to Visual Studio 2012 (v110). The target PC didn't have the C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 that was the reason of failure. After searching the installed programs I found C++ redistributable package for Visual Sudio 2010 on the target PC so I had to change the solution setting. (Go to `Project Property pages\Configuration Properties\General` and set `Platform Toolset` to whatever version you need, in my case it was Visual Studio 2010 (v100)) After rebuilding and redeploying the plugin to NSIS plugins folder I also rebuilt my installer package and this modification solved my problem.